# is it possible to automatically rotate the secrets in google secret manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I am not able to find the options to automatically rotate the secrets in google secret manager. if any options available please share here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation on [recommended methods of rotating secrets](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/rotation-recommendations#rotating-secret) and [rotation policies](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/secret-rotation) within Secrets Manager.

If your secrets are keys for doing stuff inside of Google cloud and are not regarding connecting to other services external to GCP, I would avoid using secrets.

A lot of Google services can run with different service accounts that shouldn't have keys.

Where you can't run as a service that has all the privilege you require within GCP, you can assign the privilege to perform [account impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) to impersonate other accounts that have the privilege to do the thing you need to do (which generates a short lived token under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Secret manager doesn't rotate automatically secret (as Hashicorp Vault can do).

You have feature on Secret Manager to help you to manage the rotation, such as [secret rotation deadline](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/secret-rotation), or [secret notifications](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/event-notifications). That features generate messages in a PubSub topic. Then you have to plug something, like a Cloud Functions or a Cloud Run to consume the PubSub messages.

Note: A friend of mine released [that article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-key-wars-story-a65bb9dabe56). you can take inspiration of it (the Secret Manager rotation deadline feature doesn't exist when he implemented that solution in his company)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Cloud Functions in order to automate